# Cannot load customized op shared lib in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to add a customized op to tensorflow, but I cannot load it from python. The question is similar to the closed [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2455) in github, but the solution there did not solve my problem.

Operating System: macOS 10.12

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN: None

TensorFlow 0.11.0 installed from source.

I followed the [add new op](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) tutorial, adding zero_out.cc file:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"

REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32");

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->flat<int32>();

    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      output(i) = 0;
    }

    // Preserve the first input value if possible.
    if (N > 0) output(0) = input(0);
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ZeroOut").Device(DEVICE_CPU), ZeroOutOp);
```

and bazel BUILD file:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "zero_out.so",
    srcs = ["zero_out.cc"]
)
```

then I run:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so
```

output:

```
INFO: Waiting for response from Bazel server (pid 28589)...
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.115s, Critical Path: 0.00s
```

The generated shared library located in bazel-bin. When I tried to load it like this:

```
tf.load_op_library('/Users/dtong/code/data/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so')
```

the result:

```
python(41716,0x7fffb7e123c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9e9cd2de18: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. Instead of building user op by bazel, use g++.

```
g++ -v -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC -I $TF_INC -O2 -undefined dynamic_lookup -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

It will work. The reason seems like that my gcc version is too high (v6.2.0).

The `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` is from the notion of [official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) in 'Building the Op library' section.

But I still cannot find a solution using bazel. I fired an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4989) in GitHub.